# Selecting the right path objects and move it

Tags: android, object, arraylist, path

I have stored a few path objects in a arraylist. I have problems trying to pick the right path object based on the touched coordinates x, y and move the path object around the canvas after that.

I am now able to pick the touch coordinates of the user. Android's path removes the contains method and thus I cannot use .contains(x,y) to determine the right path object and move it.

Also since my path objects are not just rectangle objects, i cannot use .computebounds either.

This is my onTouch method:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // screen touch get x of the touch event
            x = event.getX();
            // screen touch get y of the touch event
            y = event.getY();

            break;

        }

        invalidate();

     return true;
 }
```

Right now I am facing problem in picking the path containing of the screen touch x and y from the arraylist. The only method i know which is the .contains(x,y) does not work in this case.

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Robin Dijkhof i have added my codes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use points saved in a ArrayList

```
@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // screen touch point of the touch event
        myPointArrayList.add(event.getX(), event.getY());



        break;

    }

    invalidate();

 return true;
}
```

You can check for location by looping through the list.

```
for(int i = 0; i<myPointArrayList.size(); i++){
    if(myPointArrayList.get(i).getX() == myIntX && myPointArrayList.get(i).getY() == myIntY){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the Android point class does not contain getX. That means we need to create our own point class.

```
public class MyPoint{
    private float x;
    private float y;

    public MyPoint(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public float getY(){
        return y;
    }
}
```

It is also possible to create a new point and compare it.

```
for(int i = 0; i<myPointArrayList.size(); i++){
    if(myPointArrayList.get(i).equals(new PointF(myIntX, myIntY)){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

I would go for the second option, because it saves some time.

Comment: I have tried but i got this error "The method getX() is undefined for the type ArrayList<PointF>"